# visual studio 2013 - python ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, anaconda, lxml, importerror

when trying to run a Python code from within Visual Studio 2013, using Anaconda 07-2019
python environment, I get this error (the code + the error):

```
import lxml.etree
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "", line 1, in**

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found**

*What is strange is that:*

1. it's installed in Anaconda, running "conda list" from anaconda command prompt validates it.
2. when i run the same code from Jupyter lab - it succeeds!
3. when i run the same code from Spyder - it succeeds!

**so there is a problem with VS2013**.

I read a lot on the internet and tried some suggestions like updating environment path
with many paths but nothing helped.

I don't want to reinstall lxml since i suspect it's a matter of configuration/environment (and i don't have direct external internet access),
otherwise how come Spyder and Jupyter succeed?

thanks

Comment: Is that the entire error output? Can you share the result of `conda list` ?

Comment: Yes, it's the entire output. Regarding conda list, why is it needed?
i mean, if Spyder and Jupyter succeed doesn't it mean that the problem is not with Anaconda?

Comment: _Regarding conda list, why is it needed? i mean, if Spyder and Jupyter succeed doesn't it mean that the problem is not with Anaconda?_ It's to see the list of installed packages, it's possible that another package is breaking lxml.

Comment: i will try to send when i have access in a few days. but meanwhile - if another package is breaking, how come Jupyter and Spyder succeed? thanks!

Comment: _if another package is breaking, how come Jupyter and Spyder succeed?_ It could break in a way that affects only certain packages, if they share a dependency, or one is dependent on the other, for example.